# Saving javascript variable to MySql database via ajax and jsp

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, jsp

I am trying to learn about ajax and want to be able to save the timeSpentOnPage value from the [TimeMe.js](https://github.com/jasonzissman/TimeMe.js/tree/master) library into my MySql database. I have added the javascript library to my jsp page as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/timeme.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        TimeMe.initialize({
                currentPageName: "listing", // current page
                idleTimeoutInSeconds: 30 // seconds
        });     
</script>
```

There is an example on the github page for issuing a http request and using timeSpentOnPage variable:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","ENTER_URL_HERE", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var timeSpentOnPage = TimeMe.getTimeOnCurrentPageInSeconds();
    xmlhttp.send(timeSpentOnPage);
};
```

Does anyone know how i would go about adding the timeSpentOnPage variable to my database via ajax?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should also mention what you are using on server side servlets/php

Assuming you are using servlets

create a servlet and forward the AJAX request to that servlet's post method as below

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","Your Servlet Name", true);
```

You can access it in servlet as below

```
request.getParameter("timeSpentOnPage");
```

from this servlet you can do the insertion to DB using a DAO or directly based on your selection